# Failed Installation of Scipy on Mac

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, scipy

I'm trying to install the python package scipy on my work Mac (OSX Mavericks).  I have sudo privileges and have installed macports, pip, and homebrew, but cannot import scipy into python.  I get the following error when trying to import it:

> > import scipy

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    ImportError: No module named scipy
```

When trying to sudo port install scipy:

> Error: Port scipy not found

Trying sudo port install py27-scipy:

```
    Computing dependencies for py27-scipy
    Cleaning py27-scipy
    Updating database of binaries
    Scanning binaries for linking errors
    No broken files found.
```

But still unable to import scipy into python.

Using sudo pip install scipy give me this:

```
     Downloading/unpacking scipy
     Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
     Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement scipy
     Cleaning up...
     No distributions at all found for scipy
     Storing debug log for failure in /Users/philip/.pip/pip.log
```

So I am at a loss, not sure how this

Comment: Do one thing. Download the source code from [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scipy#downloads)(zip or tar.gz). Extract them, get into the extracted directory and run `python setup.py install`. If it throws any error. Post them here for further debugging.

Comment: I downloaded the tar.gz file, ran the setup, and still get the same "ImportError: No module named scipy"

Comment: Then check `PATH` environment variable. That seems to be the culprit here. Or do you have `numpy` installed already? Even that can cause few problems

Comment: I have numpy installed, it imports well and works.  Not sure why that would cause an issue.  And my current PATH is set to the anaconda python, which has scipy.  Now pyside isn't working *sarcastic yay*

Comment: Download this-[https://gist.github.com/goldsmith/7262122/download] and run it in your system.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using Anaconda to manage python under Mac? Scipy is included in the distribution. This is the 'easiest' recommended way Scipy lists to install itself on Mac.

[Anaconda Download Page](http://continuum.io/downloads)

Comment: Using Anaconda seems to have worked for importing scipy...however, a number of other errors seems to be cropping up.  I would find it simpler to install JUST scipy.